# How to move a picturebox within a panel

Tags: vb.net

I can move a picturebox from a Form to a panel as follows (both PictureBox1 and Panel1 are on the same Form control). But once it is in panel1, PictureBox1 doesn't move with MouseMove event. My intention is, once the picturebox entered the panel area, I want to move it freely (MouseMove) only within the Panel area. Can anyone help me to achieve this?

The code is this:

```html
Dim locate As Point
    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
        locate = New Point(-e.X, -e.Y)
    End Sub
    
    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            Dim MoveTo As Point = Me.PointToClient(MousePosition)
            MoveTo.locate(locate.X, locate.Y)
            If PictureBox1.Location.X < Panel1.Location.X Then
                 PictureBox1.Location = MoveTo
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: picturebox has followng properties : Top, Left, Height, Width.  Top and Left are location in parent control.  Where Top goes positive as you move from top of monitor to bottom of monitor.

Comment: Thanks;  I was trying with that.  The MouseUp event seems doing the trick